# When using in.hasNextInt(), how do I skip a string that follows in the same line?

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, filereader

After extensive searching I've not been able to come across a similar question/solution. Below is what I've written, followed by the input, and unsuccessful output. Due to the fact that it's storing the first value to create array[13], yet my array finishes empty, I suspect the comment in the first line is what's causing trouble. I should mention that I couldn't find a way to implement the .split/.replace methods since I'm working with ints and strings and I feel parsing would be a mess. I'm sure there's a workaround I'm missing here.

So,

**TL;DR : [Failure to store anything after '13'](https://textuploader.com/15h1x) – How do I skip, or line break at the "//" in the first line in the input file after storing '13'? ( If that's even what's going wrong here. )**

**Program :**

```
public class FileReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String inf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input file path?");
    java.io.FileReader inFile = new java.io.FileReader(inf);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
    String outf = "./" + JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name of new output file?");
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(outf);
    int index = in.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[index];
    MyArray MA1 = new MyArray();
    int i = 0;

    while (in.hasNextInt() && i < 13) {
        if (in.next().contains("//")){
            in.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(in);
        array[i] = in.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}}
```

**Input :**

https://textuploader.com/15h1x

**Output :**

**[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**

**Expected :**

**[573, 2739, 76321, 3873, 73430, 333, 7293, 38383, 272, 946, 3832, 8410, 2583]**

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I've updated the original post with expected output, thanks

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer or comment to ask for more ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nextLine()` everytime and then do the stuff you need :

```
while (in.hasNextLine() && i < 13) {
    line = in.nextLine();
    intval = line.split("\\s+")[0];    // check for lines with comment
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(intval);
    i++;
}
```

To read the ints that are after the 14th value :

```
List<Integer> remainingInts = new ArrayList<>();
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    line = in.nextLine();
    intval = line.split("\\s+")[0];    // check for lines with comment
    remainingInts.add(Integer.parseInt(intVal));
}
```

Comment: Should it be `Integer.parseInt(intval)` ?

Comment: ... also `hashNextLine()` should be `hasNextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because your *while* loop was never getting executed since each line of the file was being loaded as a *String* not an *int*. This also explains why your array contained only zeros.

---

Change your while-loop to the following :

```
int array[] = new int[13];
int i = 0;
in.nextLine(); // skip the first line

while (in.hasNextLine() && i < 13) {
    String currLine = in.nextLine();
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(currLine.split("\\s+")[0]);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

This outputs :

> [573, 2739, 76321, 3873, 73430, 333, 7293, 38383, 272, 946, 3832,
>   8410, 2583]

---

If you're on java-8 and higher, the entire operation can be done in a single line

```
int[] array = Files.lines(Paths.get(inFile))
                   .mapToInt(line -> Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s+")[0]))
                   .skip(1)          // skip first element
                   .limit(13)        // upto 13 only
                   .toArray();       // convert to array
```